# Why nullable value type assignment does not fail with "Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type."

Tags: c#, nullable

In C#10 I was trying to create a Result type that would have an error or a value (without going for monadic stuff).

When trying to use it I was expecting a compiler warning/error but I got nothing.

Why?

My .csproj has:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
```

The code:

```
public record Error();

public record Result<T> where T : notnull
{
    private Result()
    {
    }

    public Error? Error { get; private init; }
    public T? Value { get; private init; }
    
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Error))]
    public static implicit operator Result<T>(Error error)
    {
        return new Result<T> {Error = error};
    }
    
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Value))]
    public static implicit operator Result<T>(T result)
    {
        return new Result<T> {Value = result};
    }

    [MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(Value))]
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Error))]
    public bool IsError()
    {
        return Error is not null;
    }
}

public record TryResult
{
    public void ValueTypes()
    {
        Result<Guid> result = new Error();
        Guid value = result.Value; // no error, why?

        if (!result.IsError())
            value = result.Value;
    }
    public void RefTypes()
    {
        Result<string> result = new Error();
        string value = result.Value; // error
        
        if (!result.IsError())
            value = result.Value; // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Error` type?

Comment: Edited to add the Error type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Result<Guid> result = new Error();
var value = result.Value; // no error, why?
```

`result` is not null: it's created on the line above, through an implicit conversion from `Error`, and the implicit conversion returns a non-null `Result<T>`. So accessing `result.Value` can't fail.

Your `Value` property has type `T?` (ignoring the `MemberNotNull` stuff -- we'll come to that in the next section). Since `T` is unconstrained, the `T?` means "if `T` is a reference type, this can be null; if `T` is a value type, the `?` is ignored". Since `T` is `Guid`, this means that the property `Value` just has type `Guid`. So writing `var value = result.Value` is the same as writing `Guid value = result.Value`, which is fine.

If `T` were a reference type (such as `string`), then the `Value` property would have type `string?`, i.e. a nullable string. Even so, the compiler would infer that the `var` represents a `string?`, so that assignment would be the same as writing `string? value = result.Value`, which wouldn't cause any nullability errors.

---

```
Result<string> result = new Error();
string value = result.Value; // error
```

This time, `T` is a `string`, so the `Value` property has type `string?`. You're trying to assign this to a variable of type `string`, hence the error.

It seems that the compiler isn't able to do flow analysis from `MemberNotNull` through an implicit conversion, which I suppose makes sense. The property name you pass applies to the property on the *current instance*, but implicit conversions are static methods, and so there is no current instance for it to apply to.

---

```
if (!result.IsError())
    value = result.Value; // OK
```

Here, `MemberNotNUll` is performing as expected.

Comment: Any pointer on where can I read about ? being ignored for value types.
Also you said T is unconstrained but it is constrained to notnull. Shouldn't that make a difference?
And I hadn't noticed the MemberNotNull not working in operators. Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics), under the second bullet. "Unconstrained" here means that `T` can either be a reference or a value type -- it doesn't refer to other sorts of generic type constraints, e.g. interfaces or `notnull`.

Comment: `where T : notnull` means that you can't create a `Result<string?>`, because `string?` is nullable reference type which is forbidden by the `notnull` constraint. It doesn't force `T` to be either a reference or value type

Comment: Great, so the question is answered! Thank you!